# Proteger vídeo con Token

Tags: php, html, video, tokens, videojs

Quisiera proteger los vídeos de mi sitio web modificando la url de éstos mismos, o asignándoles un Token, pero la verdad, no tengo idea del Token todavía...
Lo que más me gustaría, sería asignarles un Token, pero en caso de no poder, quisiera que la URL del vídeo quedara algo así como los de Youtube...

> `src="blob:https://www.youtub.com/6e57f715-c81b-46ec-a142-59cc195a27d4..."`

Cualquier idea o aporte, estaré infinitamente agradecido.

Comment: Pudieras usar base64_encode para codificar tu URL y despues decodificarla con base64_decode.

Comment: Pero llevaría al usuario a una página de error... Lo que pasa es que tengo la sgte url impresa por php: {echo '<a href="'.$url.'curso/'.$value1["id"].'/'.$value1["id_usuario"].'/'.$valor[$i].'/'.$value2["ruta"].'"><button class="btn btn-default pull-left">Ir al curso</button></a>'; }
Y neceseito es que me reemplace ese href, por otra url temporal, para que no se puedan ver los parámetros...

Comment: Usas el encode64 para escoder los parametros, cuando lo recibas del otro lado usas decode64 de la misma forma para retomar la url.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui un ejemplo, de como codificar tu URL.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.youtub.com/';
echo base64_encode($url);

// Da como resultado...
aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViLmNvbS8=

?>
```